# Dropdown navigation for calendar view

Tags: views, datetime

It's not a "new" issue, but I'd like to implement a year + month dropdown selector to navigate a standard calendar view's display, as this particular calendar shows historical entries spanning many years, all of which need to be directly accessible.

I understand it's possible to specify an argument via URL to control the calendar view's current display through its contextual filter. However, I don't know how to supply this argument via a dropdown, either in the block itself or another (similar to an exposed filter), in a way that would function properly in all cases.

Working without a solution, I created my own views style plugin, added an exposed filter, and am now going to look for a way to display the easily filtered-by-month results in a custom calendar implementation through my code.

Hopefully there's a way to make use of the existing calendar module via "inspired" filtering, instead of my custom plugin route?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same requirement a few time ago.You are right the key is date pager in url to navigate through date/month/year

here is a [workaround](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73857/get-value-for-drupal-date-pager-next-or-prev-or-current) I did,might be helpfull in your case too.

As in brief I created custom form with field as month and year.Submission of the form navigates passing the selected month and year in url using drupal_goto() and we are calling this form in views header.

Comment: Thanks!

I managed to get this approach to work, which is sufficient for now. However, the ideal is a little bit more complicated.

My calendar is in a block (without a page), and this approach would have to redirect to a static location.

I'm going to look into how the existing pager updates the view without leaving the page, and see if I can implement the argument similarly.